# How to initialize dictionary with pre-defined values?

Tags: typescript

I need to create a pre-defined dictionary with the key being a city and the value an the value is an array of zones in that cities. I tried something like that

```
export const cityToZone: { [city: string]: Array<string> } = [

    {city:'New York', ['zoneA','ZoneB']}
]
```

But I keep getting an error that says:

```
(TS) Type '{ city: string; ['zoneA','ZoneB']: any; }' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'city' does not exist in type 'string[]'.
```

I'm new to typescript and I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the TypeScript community <3

Let me elaborate what is happening here:`Array<string>` (or `string[]` as they mean the same) represent a structure like `['a', 'b', 'c']`. It is different from the one you pass:  `[{city:'New York', ['zoneA','ZoneB']}]` and therefore it fails.

There are a few ways to fix this issue. I'd recommend you to change the type from `Array<string>` to `City[]` (or `Array<City>`). Based on the usage, the `City` type should be described as follows:

```
type City = {
  city: string;
  zones: string[];
};
```

and you may use it as follows:

```
export const cityToZone: City[] = [{
  city: 'New York', 
  zones: ['zoneA','ZoneB']
}];
```

**If you want to go further**, you can use union types for city names and zones:

```
type CityName = 'New York' | 'Denver' | 'Washington, D.C.'; // etc
type ZoneName = 'Zone 1' | 'Zone 2' | 'Zone 3'; // etc
```

so your `City` type will look like this:

```
type City = {
  city: CityName;
  zones: ZoneName[];
}
```

**UPD:** You can play around with it on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-j90gi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

**UPD 2 (mapping question):** If your city names are unique (e.g. you don't have to account for situations like "Moscow, Russia" and "Moscow, Idaho"), I'd recommend you to re-shape your data structure into

```
type CityMap = Record<CityName, ZoneName[]>;
```

and use it like this:

```
export const cityToZone: CityMap = {
  'New York': ['zoneA', 'zoneB'],
  'Denver': ['zoneC', 'zoneD'],
};
```

this way you can get zones by a city name in constant time (O(1))

Comment: What if I need to get all zones for some cities, do I need to loop through cityToZone array to find the city I'm looking for and then to retrieve the zones?

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for your question